# What limits debugging output speed?

Tags: c#, debugging

For control purposes, I print all values in a collection to the debug console, with

```
Debug.WriteLine(...);
```

Since I'm also watching the task manager for performance control, I noticed that neither of the 2 CPU cores is under full load while printing. RAM usage also doesn't exceed about 50%.

**Both cores have got work to do, so it's not a problem of not having enough tasks to perform**

So my question is:

What component or something like that determines the maximum speed at which the debug output can be written?

Comment: How do you even reach a point where the performance of *debug* output is a critical factor for you?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Never, I just noticed that importing data from a file puts the CPU under full load, while writing them to the debug console doesn't, although there the data is already loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that most of the time would be spent in I/O operations, i.e. writing to the logfile or the console (which might be even more expensive). So the CPU will spent the idle time waiting for the Hard drive, the GPU and/or the additional memory operations.

Comment: But why does importing data from a file put the CPU under full load, where the data has yet to be retrieved and just printing them doesn't, when the data is already available in that case?

Comment: I think that just reading data can easily be optimized for parallel execution: Data can be read and cached and prefetched into the cache, so the CPU can work more or less without interruptions/waits. Writing is usually more critical in these cases. Also output to the console tends to be really slow (compared to HD operations)